# show a license agreement in android application

Tags: android

We have to show a license agreement dialog when user use the application at the first time, now I have two questions about this:

1 Where to put this dialog?

Add another activity or put the dialog just at the `MainActivity` which is the launch acitivty?

2 How to close the app if user hit "Reject"

Once user hit the "Reject" button which means that he/she does not agree our license, then we have to exit the application completely. How to make it?

---

According to the answer of "Ahmad", I will decide to open a dialog or not at the beginning of the activity(the `onCreate` method):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    this.setupLicense();
    this.setupViews();
    this.initSomeJob();
}

private void setupLicense() {
    SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences(IConstant.Map_License, 0);
    boolean mapLicenseAccept = setting.getBoolean(IConstant.Map_License, false);
    if (!mapLicenseAccept) {
            //user does not accept the license yet, we will open the dialog
        showDialog(Dialog_Map_License);
    }
}
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    switch (id) {
        case Dialog_Map_License:
            builder.setIconAttribute(android.R.attr.alertDialogIcon)
                    .setTitle(R.string.map_license_title)
                    .setMessage(R.string.map_license_content)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.map_license_accept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            //License accepted, persisted it.
                            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(IConstant.Map_License, 0);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                            editor.putBoolean(IConstant.Map_License, true);
                            editor.commit();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.map_license_reject, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            //do nothing and exit
                            Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });
            Dialog target = builder.create();
            target.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            return target;
    }
    return null;
}
```

But now I have meet two problem:

1 Event I choose the "Accept" button, once I open my app the second time, the dialog will show.

It seems that the following code does not work:

```
                            editor.putBoolean(IConstant.Map_License, true);
                            editor.commit();
```

2 When I show the dialog, the code:

```
this.setupViews();
this.initSomeJob();
```

will still run , they are not blocked which is out of expected, since nothing should be done before user hit the "Accept" button.

Any idea to fix  it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onCreateDialog has been deprecated. Use dialog fragment instead. The advantage will be that the code for displaying dialog will be moved from activity and you can then display dialog from any activity. Also move

```
SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences(IConstant.Map_License, 0);
boolean mapLicenseAccept = setting.getBoolean(IConstant.Map_License, false);
```

to a utility method like isLicenceAccepted and similarly for storing the data

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(IConstant.Map_License, 0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
 editor.putBoolean(IConstant.Map_License, true);
 editor.commit();
```

to method like acceptLicence in utility.
You can find how to make communication between dialog Fragment and your activity [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html). In your interface instead of `onArticleSelected` you will have to implement two methods onLicence accepted and onLicenceRejected. Implement the interface in you activity override these two methods and take appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

> Where to put this dialog?

Right at the beginning, when the user opens the app for the first time. Keep track of that by saving it in your shared preferences, if this dialog has been already shown or not. You don't have to create a separate activity for this. You could, but most apps I've seen out there don't.

> How to close the app if user hit "Reject"

Just finish the Activity and also save that in your shared preferences as well. So every time the user opens your app you check weather the boolean value for "hasUserAcceptedOurAgreement" is true or not and proceed depending on that.

---

I'm only answering from a technical standpoint on how this could be done reliably. I'm not a lawyer, but as far as I know, it's perfectly valid to just submit your license agreement to the play store, so it's available from the applications application page (*Why else would there be this option?*).

Comment: Ahmad, 1:do you mean that add the license dialog as one part of the `MainActivity`, and display or hide them accordingly? 2:What do you  mean by "finish the activity"? And the "submit license agreement to play store" you mentioned sounds great, I will try both.:)