# Can we show Agreement PopUp while installing on paid app before payment in PlayStore

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Can we show the Licence Agreement Details in the continue popup as shown in the image attachment [PopUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxToP.png) when we try to install a paid app in play store.

If so tell me that where i can mention the Agreement Details of the App before Purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20767991/show-a-license-agreement-in-android-application), you may use dialog fragment. The advantage will be that the code for displaying dialog will be moved from activity and you can then display dialog from any activity.

This [tutorial](https://jayeshcp.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/showing-eula-in-android-app/) discussed how to implement EULA (End User License Agreement) in android apps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to show the Agreement pop-Up during installation of app in play store not in the application